# Netbeans not displaying system.out.println();

Tags: java

I am taking a java class at a community college online and I am stuck on one of the examples of the book. I do not know what happen but when I run the code it says successful but does not display the message. Up to this point it was displaying the message no problem but now it has stopped and I am using netbeans for my IDE.  Thanks for the help in advance.

```
public class ParadiseInfo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        displayInfo();
    }

    public static void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("Paradise Day Spa wants to pamper you. ");
        System.out.println("We will make you look good. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. You can use `Run File` (Shift+F6) to run just the file or check the project properties to make sure that the "Main Class" is set correctly in the "Run" properties

Comment: I have done that and even open pass files from the previous chapters and they run fun and displaying the message. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If all the other programs run and print fine, then maybe you're not actually running *that* program when you think you do. Try deleting it and starting over. It's not that big.

Comment: Try performing a clean and build; try removing any other `main` methods which may exist in the project

Comment: yeah I am just going to start over again in the morning right now I need some sleep thanks!